Flutter postgres and compute
I'm currently developing a desktop app that directly talks with a postgres database. Because the insertions take dozens of minutes to complete and freeze the UI, I've read online that this process can become "multithreaded" by using isolate or compute. Unfortunately, I get an error when using compute saying that connection cannot be passed in an isolate. 
This is the complete code that is executed. And this is the error that I get:

import 'package:excel/excel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';

import '../ConnectionRelated/PostgresConnectionHelper.dart';
import '../ConnectionRelated/RawQueryRunner.dart';

// A class to hold isolate parameters
class TaskParams {
  final Connection connection;
  final Sheet table;
  final int temperatureId;
  final String temperatureDataArray;

  TaskParams(this.connection, this.table, this.temperatureId,
      this.temperatureDataArray);
}

class TemperatureDataInserter2 {
  static void test_function(TaskParams taskParams) async {
    //
    // Connection connection, Sheet table,
    // int temperatureId, String temperatureDataArray
    Sheet? table= taskParams.table;
    Connection connection = taskParams.connection;
    int temperatureId = taskParams.temperatureId;
    String temperatureDataArray = taskParams.temperatureDataArray;

    // Fetch Fluoresence data from column 2 until 49, column indices 1 to 48
    for (int column = 1; column < table.rows[0].length; column++) {
      List<double> fluorescenceData = [];

      for (int i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        var cellValue = table.rows[i][column]?.value;
        // Check the type of cell value and convert it to double
        if (cellValue is double) {
          fluorescenceData.add(cellValue);
        } else if (cellValue is int) {
          fluorescenceData.add(cellValue.toDouble());
        }
      }

      // Convert the Fluorescence data list to a PostgreSQL array format
      String fluorescenceDataArray = fluorescenceData.join(',');

      int temperatureIdOffset = temperatureId + column;

      String insertQuery = """
          INSERT INTO public.temperature_data (dna_test_id,
           temperature_celsius_array,
           fluorescence_array)
          VALUES ($temperatureIdOffset,
           ARRAY[$temperatureDataArray]::double precision[],
           ARRAY[$fluorescenceDataArray]::double precision[]);
          """;

      await new RawQueryRunner().run(connection, insertQuery);

      // final result = await compute(fibonacci, 40);
      // print('Fibonacci result: $result');
    }
  }

  Future<void> Execute(Excel excel) async {
    // if (!excel.tables.containsKey(sheetName)) {
    //   print('Sheet "$sheetName" does not exist');
    //   return;
    // }

    // final table = excel.tables[sheetName];
    final table = excel.tables["High Resolu…Melt Target Data"];
    if (table == null) {
      print('Table for sheet "$table" is null');
      return;
    } else {
      print('Table sheet name is: "$table"');
    }

    // // TableRowPrinter().run(table);
    // var table2 = excel.tables["Samples"]!;

    // SamplePrinter().run(table2);

    Connection? connection = await PostgresConnectionHelper().Connect();

    if (connection != null) {
      String sql = """
      INSERT INTO public.dna_test (id)
      SELECT nextval('test_results_id_seq')
      FROM generate_series(1, 48);
      """;

      // Adds 48 empty dna_tests with (the dna_test.id is auto incremental)
      await new RawQueryRunner().run(connection, sql);

      // Get the max id after inserting the new records
      String getMaxIdSql = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM public.dna_test";
      List<List<dynamic>> result = await connection.execute(getMaxIdSql);

      int maxId = result.first.first;
      int temperatureId = maxId - 48;

      // First column is temperatureData which is
      // second row first column (index 1,0)
      List<double> temperatureData = [];
      for (int i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        var cellValue = table.rows[i][0]?.value;
        // Check the type of cell value and convert it to double
        if (cellValue is double) {
          temperatureData.add(cellValue);
        } else if (cellValue is int) {
          temperatureData.add(cellValue.toDouble());
        }
      }

      // Declaring and assigning the
      // maxTemperatureValue and minTemperatureValue
      var maxTemperatureValue = temperatureData[0];
      var minTemperatureValue = temperatureData[0];

      for (var i = 0; i < temperatureData.length; i++) {
        // Checking for largest value in the list
        if (temperatureData[i] > maxTemperatureValue) {
          maxTemperatureValue = temperatureData[i];
        }

        // Checking for smallest value in the list
        if (temperatureData[i] < minTemperatureValue) {
          minTemperatureValue = temperatureData[i];
        }
      }

      List<double> temperatureDataMinMaxRange = [];

      // Round the min and max Values on the 2 digits
      var roundedMinTemperatureValue =
          (minTemperatureValue * 100).roundToDouble() / 100;
      var roundedMaxTemperatureValue =
          (maxTemperatureValue * 100).roundToDouble() / 100;

      // Printing the values
      print("Smallest rounded value in the list : $roundedMinTemperatureValue");
      print("Largest rounded value in the list : $roundedMaxTemperatureValue");

      temperatureDataMinMaxRange.add(roundedMinTemperatureValue);
      temperatureDataMinMaxRange.add(roundedMaxTemperatureValue);

      // Convert the temperature data list to a PostgreSQL array format
      String temperatureDataArray = temperatureDataMinMaxRange.join(',');


      //The original code which must become multi threaded
      // Fetch Fluoresence data from column 2 until 49, column indices 1 to 48
      for (int column = 1; column < table.rows[0].length; column++) {
        List<double> fluorescenceData = [];

        for (int i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
          var cellValue = table.rows[i][column]?.value;
          // Check the type of cell value and convert it to double
          if (cellValue is double) {
            fluorescenceData.add(cellValue);
          } else if (cellValue is int) {
            fluorescenceData.add(cellValue.toDouble());
          }
        }

        // Convert the Fluorescence data list to a PostgreSQL array format
        String fluorescenceDataArray = fluorescenceData.join(',');

        int temperatureIdOffset = temperatureId + column;

        String insertQuery = """
          INSERT INTO public.temperature_data (dna_test_id,
           temperature_celsius_array,
           fluorescence_array)
          VALUES ($temperatureIdOffset,
           ARRAY[$temperatureDataArray]::double precision[],
           ARRAY[$fluorescenceDataArray]::double precision[]);
          """;

        await new RawQueryRunner().run(connection, insertQuery);
      }

      // The code where isolate crashes because it can't accept connection
      await compute(test_function,
          TaskParams(connection, table, temperatureId, temperatureDataArray));
    }
  }
}


Isolate.run() has a slightly more flexible interface.  In fact, compute() is now written using Isolate.run(). :)

Please don't post textual information as an image or link to an image. Please see Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? Also, review [mre] and consider reducing the presented code to the minimum required to demonstrate the issue. Besides making it easier for the SO community to identify relevant code, it might also help the author discover the cause of the problem.

Managed to fix it by creating a new connection inside the test_function like this
Connection? connection = await PostgresConnectionHelper().Connect();

However I would be interested to know if it's possible and a good practice to pass connection as a parameter.

No, it's not possible. Have the isolate make its own connection.

The PostgresConnectionHelper creates a new connection.
